# ASP.NET Cast ArrayList of objects to custom Objects

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Hey Just getting the following error

Unable to cast object of type 'System.Object[]' to type 'OrderService.webdirect_WebLinesRow[]'.

On the line

```
webdirect(web_companyID, web_locationCode, web_customerNumber, web_orderNumber, web_orderReference, web_orderDate, webLinesArray.ToArray(), o_Company, o_LocationCode, o_CustomerNumber, o_OrderNumber, o_OrderStatus, o_OrdDescrip, webRespArray)
```

I created the webLinesArray.ToArray() array as such

```
Dim webLinesArray As New ArrayList()
```

Am I missing an additional cast or something ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try out using System.Linq:

```
webLinesArray.Cast(of WebLinesRow)().ToArray()
```

instead of

```
webLinesArray.ToArray()
```

BTW,

why are you using legacy `ArrayList`? Try out generic `List<T>`

Comment: @StevieB : linq is supported in vs2008 / .net framework 3.5. It is a standalone library that has no dependency on (asp.net ???) mvc.

Comment: yeah I tried webLinesArray.Cast<WebLinesRow>().ToArray() but getting error Cast is not a member of System.Collections.ArrayList

Comment: Cool tried that but now getting Error 6 Type parameter 'TResult' for extension method 'Public Function Cast(Of TResult)() As System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable(Of TResult)' defined in 'System.Linq.Enumerable' cannot be inferred.

Comment: It's VB.NET so `using` should be `Imports System.Linq` and the cast should be `webLinesArray.Cast(Of WebLinesRow)()`.

Comment: @Steve: drop `ArrayList`, it's not used anymore.